# MS Access SQL table constraint

Tags: ms-access

I am trying to create a table in MS Access 2016 by using a query .I am trying to make the rating have a constraint >=1  , here is the query:

```
CREATE TABLE movies 
(
     movie_id AUTOINCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
     title VARCHAR (30) NOT NULL,
     rating INT,  
     CONSTRAINT CHK_rate CHECK (rating >= 1),
     release_date DATE NOT NULL 
);
```

However I cannot save/execute it, because it says I have error in `Constraint` clause, where can be the problem?

Comment: See also [CurrentProject.Connection.Execute strSql](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15468671/77335)  Your `CREATE TABLE` succeeds in Access 2010 using that approach, so should also work in Access 2016.

Comment: @Hansup, better reference. It works. Interesting thing is nothing shows in Validation Rule property but the rule must have been saved somewhere. Also, table does not immediately show up in Navigation Pane. Pane must be refreshed.

Comment: @Lara S., why need to programmatically create table?

Comment: @June7 Although there is similar functionality between check constraints and validation rules, they are different features. One of the drawbacks to check constraints is that they can't be viewed and managed with the Access UI features.

Comment: And when I try to delete table with Delete key or right click shortcut menu, I get error. Had to use DoCmd.DeleteObject method. Annoying. I would not use this method to create table.