# SQL Create Table Syntax Error on Constraint

Tags: sql, ms-access

While trying to create some tables with constraints I have stumbled on syntax errors. I am using Microsoft Access and it keeps advising me that my second Constraint is wrong. What is going on? My code looks as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE STORE 
(
StoreName Char(25) NOT NULL,
City Char(35) NULL
Country Char(50) NULL,
Phone Char(8) NULL,
Fax Char(15) NULL,
Email Varchar(100) NULL,
Contact Char(35) NULL,
CONSTRAINT StorePK PRIMARY KEY(StoreName),
CONSTRAINT Citizen CHECK (Country IN ('Belize', 'United States', 'Mexico','China', 'Germany', 'France', 'Netherlands'))
);
```

Comment: I am not aware that MS Access supports check constraints:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff836971.aspx#sectionSection0.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to create a check constraint in access and/or DAO?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1660512/is-it-possible-to-create-a-check-constraint-in-access-and-or-dao)

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have to create the table and the use `ALTER TABLE` to add the constraint.

```
ALTER TABLE STORE
CONSTRAINT Citizen CHECK (
    Country IN (
        'Belize', 'United States', 'Mexico','China',
        'Germany', 'France', 'Netherlands'
    )
);
```

I don't know how much the situation has changed since Access 2000 I'm pretty certain that some limitations still apply as indicated in this old documentation:

> **Note** The check constraint statement can only be executed through the Jet OLE DB provider and ADO; it will return an error message if
>   used though the Access SQL View user interface.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa140015%28office.10%29.aspx#acintsql_ddlconst

Answer (score 1):

Your `CREATE TABLE` statement is valid Access DDL when executed from ADO/OleDb.  `CHECK` constraints are among the DDL features added with Jet 4, and which are not supported under DAO.

That also means `CHECK` is not supported by default for queries run from the query designer.  You might be able to work around that limitation by setting the Access option *"SQL Server Compatible Syntax (ANSI 92)"*.  However that option has other side effects.  If you use it, make sure to test your existing queries to see whether they all still operate as intended.

I put your statement text in a variable and executed it successfully like this:

```vb
CurrentProject.Connection.Execute strDDL
```

That worked because `CurrentProject.Connection` is an ADO object.