# Microsoft Access - CHECK errors

Tags: sql, ms-access, check-constraints, check-constraint

these are the requirements that we have to use SQL to code and we have to build in a check on the table.

I can't find a helpful answer --

```
CREATE TABLE data
(
data_Name VARCHAR(10) UNIQUE,
data_totals INT,

CONSTRAINT [data_totals_test] CHECK (data_totals between 1 and 5 )
);
```

error message:

```
syntax error in constraint clause
```

if i do it like this

```
CREATE TABLE data
(
data_Name VARCHAR(10) UNIQUE,
data_totals INT,

CHECK (data_totals between 1 and 5 )
);
```

or this

```
CREATE TABLE data
(
data_Name VARCHAR(10) UNIQUE,
data_totals INT,

CHECK (data_totals > 1 and data_totals < 5 )
);
```

i get error message in both cases --

```
syntax error in field definition
```

if i take out the , after INT then I get the error message:

```
syntax error in Create Table Statement.
```

also tried this:

create a table this way (successfully)

```
CREATE TABLE data
(
data_Name VARCHAR(10) UNIQUE,
data_totals INT
);
```

tried using alter:

```
alter table data ADD CHECK (data_totals > 1 );
```

got the same error:

```
syntax error in field definition
```

please advise.

Comment: Are you executing those statements using `CurrentProject.Connection.Execute`? That's required for those types of statements.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1660512/is-it-possible-to-create-a-check-constraint-in-access-and-or-dao

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth I will be honest, i am not sure what that means. I am in a project in access -- and i am clicking on Run from a sql query window.

Comment: @MichaelEvanchik i did see another question but nothing was clear or helpful in the solution and im sorry for the duplication of post but i am stuck with this

Comment: @Elizabeth, in VBA, you will need to execute this, after you just create the table without the constraint

Comment: @MichaelEvanchik (apologies for not knowing more) but if i am not sure how to do that where can i learn more. my instructions are to use sql to create a table with these constraints

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to create a check constraint in access and/or DAO?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1660512/is-it-possible-to-create-a-check-constraint-in-access-and-or-dao)

Comment: @Elizabeth smack the person who is making you use Microsoft access

Comment: @ashleedawg as i mentioned in the previous comment, i tried looking for other quires but couldn't find a solution to how to script this. since my visual basic knowledge is supper is negligible i'm trying to sort this out in sql.

Comment: @MichaelEvanchik (as lovely as that would be its an educational institution so it would not go far).

Comment: i think you can do it in SQL hang in there, i dont have it installed having  trouble to help

Comment: does this not work

CREATE TABLE data 
       ( data_name varchar(10) unique, data_totals INTEGER,
check (id < 5),  
constraint Mypk primary key (id) )


yes i know we have to do > 1 but just try this first

Comment: it might be as simple as it does not like your "AND"

Comment: also try using the word INTEGER

Comment: i cant help you accept trial an error,  control G opens another way to enter code

Comment: @MichaelEvanchik will try those shortly. Thank you.

Comment: @MichaelEvanchik it still doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this  https://support.office.com/en-us/article/customize-design-settings-for-objects-in-your-database-b6e0baa0-15d4-47ae-84c2-e0c46dcea23b

to set to ANSI 92 SQL

```
CREATE TABLE data
(
data_Name VARCHAR(10) UNIQUE,
data_totals INT CHECK (data_totals > 1 and data_totals < 5)
);
```

alternatively

```
CREATE TABLE data
(
data_Name VARCHAR(10) UNIQUE,
data_totals INT,
CONSTRAINT CHK_data_totals CHECK (data_totals>1 AND data_totals<5)
);
```

Comment: also what is the access version, fyi between is <= and >= fyi and not the same

Comment: data reserved word?

Comment: technically its a ValidationRule , let me spin up a vm

Comment: please change to https://support.office.com/en-us/article/customize-design-settings-for-objects-in-your-database-b6e0baa0-15d4-47ae-84c2-e0c46dcea23b

Comment: SQL Server compatible syntax (ANSI 92)

This database Select this option when you want to run queries against Microsoft SQL Server databases. You must use ANSI-92 syntax for all queries when you select this option. Existing queries written using the older ANSI-89 standard (the default for Access) might not run, or might return unexpected results.

Comment: otherwise u will need to do it via the designer of the table visually or ado va code

Comment: thank you please mark as answer with the star and push the up button so the community understands it was the answer